# Possible ways of animating appendTo and prependTo in horizontal list

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

There is simple gallery plugin, and i'm wondering is there any ways to animate scrolling effect ( from left to right and vice versa) in this implementation of changing slides(using append in ul array, not margins)?

Below is the snippet, imagine that black border is your viewport.

```js
function moveLeft() {
    var last = $('ul li:last-child');
    last.prependTo('ul');
};
function moveRight() {
    var first = $('ul li:first-child');
    first.appendTo('ul');
};

$('a.next').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    moveRight();
});

$('a.prev').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    moveLeft();
});
```

```css
ul{
    white-space:nowrap;
}
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 15px;
}

.viewport{
    position:absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left:100px;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
<div class="viewport">
</div>
    
<a href="" class="prev">Previous</a>
<a href="" class="next">Next</a>
```

Comment: Animate wont work since im not using css ( margins ) here. Am i wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution, it works well enough, but there's definite improvements to be made. I made the `ul { position: relative }`, after prepending/appending the item immediately offset it's position using `left` or `right` css attributes, and then animated these values using jquery back to `0`.

Moreover, its important that the previous animation queue is cleared with `jquery.stop()`, and that the `left`/`right` value is reset, depending on the attribute being animated.

I did some tweaking on the numbers to make it look right - if you modify its current size or styling, you will have to tweak the exact css values again, but the principle will be exactly the same. Hope this helps.

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmdk64a5/2/